# Why arrow function return shows undefined?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, event-handling, arrow-functions

My "billInput" function dosent return input field (event.target.value) value. Where no-1 console.log (below commented) show input value in console.

I tried to send those value (no-2 console.log commented below) on global scope variable that also doesn't work.

```
let billAmount = 0;

const billInput = (event) => {
  const getValue = parseInt(event.target.value);
  const totalPeopleElement = document.getElementById("total-poeple");
  totalPeopleElement.innerText = getValue;
  //1: console.log(getValue);
  // 2: billAmount = getValue;
  return getValue;
};
const totalBill = document.getElementById("bill-input").addEventListener("input", billInput);

// 3:console.log(billAmount);
console.log(totalBill);
```

Comment: `addEventListener` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Also, your second test, setting the outer scoped billAmount is working, but the outer console.log only runs once, not on every click so you're not seeing the change.

Comment: But, my 2nd console.log doesn't work for input event. It just shows default initializing value 0 on console.